# Error: Unrecognized font family Material Design icons after installing react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native

I am a Newbie in react-native. I created a new project using react-native-cli.
I am Using react-native-elements As A UI component library for React Native. So I ran following commands

```
**npm i react-native-elements --save**
```

After this i ran my simulator command,

**`react-native run-ios`**

not sure how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try running the following command -

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

if this does not solve your problem then once you rebuild your app using,

```
react-native run-ios
```

sometimes CLI is not able to get the updates automatically.

Comment: Hello @abhushek ,
In my case, after following your steps  I  had to  dragged node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIcons.xcodeproj to Libraries and again libRNVectorIcons.a to Linked Frameworks and library list . 

Thank you

Comment: I am using react-native version 5.0.1 and it gives the following error: _error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")_

Comment: npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons worked fine

Answer (score 62):

If you are coming from react-native 0.60+ so please add the UIAppFonts (below mention) in info.plist file . And drag and drop the fonts folder under node_modules/react-native-vector-icons to the project in xcode. **Make sure your app is checked under "Add to targets" and that "Create groups" is checked if you add the whole folder.**

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This solution Working fine. There is 3 info.plist file in ios sub folders. Added above code in all 3 places. Then i Run "pod install" command. then i run "react-native run-ios" command. working fine. I had above listed all .tiff files in node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts folder.

Comment: In my case did not had to touch anything related to TTF files itself, just modify info.plist by adding all fonts, if I added just some it dod not work

Answer (score 39):

Just add these lines in info.plist, delete the `build/` folder inside `ios` folder and rebuild the app `npx react-native run-ios`
It worked for me.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Above worked fine. Didn't have to delete `build` folder inside `ios`

Answer (score 12):

Add the given code in the info.plist file in folder yourAppName/info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

and then in the terminal run

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
npx react-native run-ios //if react-native installed then just react-native run-ios
```

Comment: pod install // worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Ok, so for the people who didn't find the above answer helpful, I just added this into info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

and then go to `ios` folder and run pod install. Run again the app and it should work

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above says you should add `MaterialIcons.ttf` into your info.plist and any other ttf that you're using like this:

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
 <array>
   <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
   <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
   (write here any other .ttf you're using)
 </array>
```

But if you're using CocoaPods you should also add to `Podfile` this line:

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

Then run the following and it'll probably fix it (if you're already in ios folder skip the first line):

```
cd ios
pod update
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

Source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: For version `9.2.0` it was needed to add the pod address directly in the `Podfile`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it for me:

1. Shutdown simulator
2. Add to ios/{AppName}/info.plist

```
  <key>UIAppFonts</key> (Should already be there)
  <array>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  </array>
```

3. Run

```
  cd ios
  pod install
  cd ..
  watchman watch-del-all
```

4. Restart simulator

NOTE: I assume you can do this for every font family you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was facing the same issue **'Error Unrecognized font-family Material Design Icons...'** but combined with this other issue on Xcode **'Multiple commands produce'**.
Below are the steps that solved my problem:

- npx react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons
- npm uninstall react-native-vector-icons
- Delete the 'node_modules' folder
- npm install (at the root of the project)
- cd ios
- pod install
- cd ..
- Reinstall react-native-vector-icons following the options available here(i took the CocoaPods one in my case) https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios

Answer (score 0):

I have completed all of the solutions above and I am still receiving the same error message.  I am not directly importing the specific Icon but instead referencing as shown in the "react-native-paper" documentation as shown below.  I suspect this may be causing a problem?

```
<TextInput
            placeholder="password"
            mode="outlined"
            value={selected.password}
            label="Password"
            onChangeText={text => dispatch.models_userAuth.setPass(text)}
            secureTextEntry={hidden}
            right={
              hidden ? (
                <TextInput.Icon
                  icon="eye"
                  onPress={() => setHidden(!hidden)}
                />
              ) : (
                <TextInput.Icon
                  icon="eye-off"
                  onPress={() => setHidden(!hidden)}
                />
              )
            }
          />
```