# Unrecognized font family 'Material Icons'

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have used React Native elements in my React Native Project. Then I got the below error.
Note: I have linked the React Native Element

IOS Simulator result

[image: IOS Simulator result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unrecognized font family Material Design icons after installing react-native-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601206/error-unrecognized-font-family-material-design-icons-after-installing-react-nat)

Comment: Its might an issue withe image file not the library. Check the image is there and restart package manager

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880817/3437900

Answer (score 0):

Make sure fonts are included in both iOS and Android projects after linking

Or See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880817/3437900

Comment: We've faced the same issue and the resolution was to link manually